# 18.04 Total Loss of Connectivity (Wifi&Eth) after Update

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ip

I left my Ubuntu 18.04 to download the new packages from software updater. When I got back I had no more internet connectivity. If I try ping google.com I get

```
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

I tried to connect via ethernet as well no to avail, I also tried another connection at another house, still to no avail. All my other devices are working fine. So it`s not something that has to do with router (which I tried to reset a couple of times). My router sees my computer in the list of connected devices. When I try to access router from my computer at 192.168.1.1 the connection times out. Everything (gateway, ip, etc) is set to default. I tried flushing the routing table which didn't help (might have created more problems). I've been trying to fix this for a day or so but unfortunately haven't figured it out yet! would appreciate the help

update:ran `nmcli device`

```
wlp2s0:connected to NETGEAR 22
"Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter'
wifi (ath9k), B8:EE:65:8B:84:68, hw, mtu 1500
ip4 default
inet4 192.168.1.3/24
route4 0.0.0.0/0
route4 192.168.1.0/24
route4 169.254.0.0/16
inet6 fe80:fd5f:7f15:c5d4:4067/64
route6 ff00::/8
route6 ff80::/64
route6 ff08::/64


enp1s0fi: unavailable
"Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller"
ethernet (r8169), F8:A9:63:72:7C:82, hw, mtu1500

lo: unmanaged
"lo"
loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
servers: 192.168.1.1
interface: wlp2s0
```

Edit: seems like a few people are having network issues after updating, might be a kernel update? Did try to boot using 4.15.0-70-generic but no luck.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/372975/ping-sendmsg-operation-not-permitted-error-after-installing-iptables-on-arch-g